# How to find the directions of object without using distance function?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I am trying to solve a problem - find the direction of movement of objects. Say for example, how many cars moving in/out on perticular region. Now I have series of Bounding Boxes or Centroid of Bounding Boxes from Tracking Algorithm. Now I want to know which direction those boxes are moving?

```
image/frame from video
_______________________________
|
|
|            North
| 
|                  BBox(X,Y)
|    
|               
|       
|            South
```

Now if you see above, I want to know for next frame the BBox is moving towards `North` or `South`.

#### More information

Currently I am using Distance formula, which is kind of not working for all cases. Is there any other technique in `Math` I can use to determine the direction ?

```
  frames[0-n] # series of frames say frame.shape=(w,h)
  bboxes[0-n] # series of co-ordinates, Bbox on Oth frame to nth frame. 
  north = (x, y)
  south = (p, q)

function direction(frames, bboxes)
   // math ?
   return south or north
```

#### Application overview

Here in below image, I want to know where students are moving towards. In this below, three students are moving north and 1 moving south

[image: Image for example]

Comment: Please suggests some tags for this problem.

Comment: Do you mean you're currently converting a difference, say $(x,\,y)$, to a unit vector by dividing it by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but want a different approach?

Comment: Yes, right now I am using  'distance' formula b/w two points. That is BBox and North/South Point. I decide it is moving to north if its distance is near to north. I am searching for some other approach, like using motion vector or optical flow.

Comment: @J.G. - `sqrt( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2) - exact code. added some more clarity also

Comment: Is it possible the reason it's "not working for all cases" because you haven't taken $z_1,\,z_2$ into account?

Comment: yes, that is also a reason. Since, I am doing math in 'pixel' co-ordinates. Ideally, if I can convert it into Camera Co-ordinate then 'distance' approach might work for all cases(because you will get `x,y,z` points.

Comment: You can't deduce distance in $3$-dimensional space from distance in the pixels' $2$-dimensional plane alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112033/discussion-between-ajayramesh-and-j-g).